# Vertical single-page fuild CSS layout

Tags: javascript, css, fluid-layout, singlepage

I wanted to know if anyone could provide more insight into the design style of the following website:

http://mailchimp.com/goes-with-you/

I'd like how certain elements remain fixed, while others are responsive, and appear behind layers etc.

Basically I would like to learn more about this style of layout, what it's called, and I wanted to know if anyone could provide me with some links to online resources that go a little further into similar designs.

Any information would be very very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: seems like a wise use of bootstrap classes and use several images, use firebug to dig more; you can learn about boostrap here [latest 3.0.0] http://getbootstrap.com and http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known as **Parallax Scrolling** effect. There are many tutorials about it. Just try to use the web search with this keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for details about layout style called parallax:

http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/parallax-scrolling-1131762

There are js libraries like jQuery.parallax and parallax.js that may help you developing such a site.